# AppCenter - Failed to Fetch updates?

Tags: release-juno, updates, appcenter

I have a problem with appcenter show me

THIS PROBLEM ??

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/birdie-team/daily/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.

W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/birdie-team/stable/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.

W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details

**  I can't update any apps :(
```

Comment: [Cross posted on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/1152709/816190)

Answer (score 1):

You must have previously added the PPA for 'Birdie' app to your system's repositories list. But as Birdie has gotten quite old and apparently hasn't been  released for Ubuntu 18.04 (bionic), your system can't find the proper 'bionic' release file in that particular PPA, displays an error message and can't proceed with other updates.

To fix the AppCenter update process, you could remove Birdie PPA from your system's PPA list. You can read how to do it [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed).